# Python - asyncio - Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

**Description: (simplified)**

- I have 2 tasks.
- Within each task I have 3 coroutines.
- 2 coroutines from the first task fail. (simulated)
- While processing task results, I am getting one "Task exception was never retrieved" message.
- I believe this is because exception of only one of the two failed coroutines in that task was processed.
- How do I process exceptions of both coroutines within task and/or avoid the "Task exception was never retrieved" message?

**Code: (simplified)**

```
import asyncio
async def download(data):
    filename = "*" if data in ["b", "c"] else data  # simulated failure
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
async def coro(data_list):
    coroutines = [download(data) for data in data_list]
    for coroutine in asyncio.as_completed(coroutines):
        await coroutine
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(coro(["a", "b", "c"]))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(coro(["d", "e", "f"]))
    results = await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, return_exceptions=True)
    for _ in results:
        pass
asyncio.run(main())
```

**Output: (simplified)**

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<download() done, defined at D:/myscript.py:2> exception=OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/myscript.py", line 4, in download
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '*'
```

Comment: Can you repeat the same issue with public URLs, so that we can try it out and reproduce it?

Comment: @user4815162342 - Thanks. Yes, I have simplified the code drastically and made it reproducible. Also narrowed down the problem to asyncio only. Please refer the edited question.

Comment: Maybe you went too far with the simplification because this is a completely different error - Windows doesn't like the `*` character in file names, and file name globbing doesn't work with Python's `open()` anyway.

Comment: Ya. I added incorrect file name `*` on purpose to just simulate task exceptions and see how to retrieve all of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to collect exceptions instead of raising them, you can use `asyncio.gather(return_exceptions=True)` in `coro` as well. For example:

```
import asyncio

async def download(data):
    if data in ['b', 'c']:
        1/0    # simulate error
    return 42  # success

async def coro(data_list):
    coroutines = [download(data) for data in data_list]
    return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines, return_exceptions=True)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(coro(["a", "b", "c"]))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(coro(["d", "e", "f"]))
    return await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, return_exceptions=True)

print(asyncio.run(main()))
```

This will print:

```
[[42, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'), ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')], [42, 42, 42]]
```